# Can all contents of a folder be "automatically" be categorized in Plone 4.1?

Tags: plone

In  plone if I make a  folder, all the content items i.e files, folders, images in that particular folder should **automatically** be categorized under that folder. So when I make a collection to view all the contents of the folder, only those should be visible in the collection. I need not tag each of the contents with a tag and create the collection i.e an automatic tag (inherent tag for the folder contents) should be created for its contents. How can this be achieved in Plone 4.1?

Comment: Why not use a path constraint? Collections can already be told to only show content from a specific folder with that.

Comment: I had not noticed the 'location' field which could be used for that purpose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create (or edit) the collection, you can add a Location criterion, and specify the path to the folder.  After you save, the collection will only show content from inside that folder (and, in addition to this criterion, all other criteria you have added as filters for that collection).

Answer (score 0):

We need to use Location and add the subfolders (if required) as 1 of the criterion for the collection.